# ssh key permission denied after severral attempt

Tags: ssh, ubuntu-14.04

I accessed several time to a server. And I could connect perfectly. this evening I want to connect again it gives me an error.

```
-> % ssh ubuntu@pkp-alm.lib.sfu.ca -v                          
OpenSSH_6.6.1, OpenSSL 1.0.1f 6 Jan 2014
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 19: Applying options for *
debug1: Connecting to pkp-alm.lib.sfu.ca [52.4.177.245] port 22.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: identity file /home/guinsly/.ssh/id_rsa type 1
debug1: identity file /home/guinsly/.ssh/id_rsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /home/guinsly/.ssh/id_dsa type -1
debug1: identity file /home/guinsly/.ssh/id_dsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /home/guinsly/.ssh/id_ecdsa type -1
debug1: identity file /home/guinsly/.ssh/id_ecdsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /home/guinsly/.ssh/id_ed25519 type -1
debug1: identity file /home/guinsly/.ssh/id_ed25519-cert type -1
debug1: Enabling compatibility mode for protocol 2.0
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_6.6.1p1 Ubuntu-2ubuntu2.3
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version OpenSSH_6.6.1p1 Ubuntu-2ubuntu2
debug1: match: OpenSSH_6.6.1p1 Ubuntu-2ubuntu2 pat OpenSSH_6.6.1* compat 0x04000000
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
debug1: kex: server->client aes128-ctr hmac-md5-etm@openssh.com none
debug1: kex: client->server aes128-ctr hmac-md5-etm@openssh.com none
debug1: sending SSH2_MSG_KEX_ECDH_INIT
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_ECDH_REPLY
debug1: Server host key: ECDSA c6:7c:32:1c:70:96:6e:ea:c0:84:96:79:3a:6c:06:bb
debug1: Host 'pkp-alm.lib.sfu.ca' is known and matches the ECDSA host key.
debug1: Found key in /home/guinsly/.ssh/known_hosts:21
debug1: ssh_ecdsa_verify: signature correct
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
debug1: Roaming not allowed by server
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_REQUEST sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Offering RSA public key: /home/guinsly/.ssh/id_rsa
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey
debug1: Offering RSA public key: guinslym@gmail.com
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey
debug1: Offering RSA public key: guinsly@guinsly-ThinkPad-L430
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey
debug1: Offering RSA public key: guinslym@gmail.com
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey
debug1: Trying private key: /home/guinsly/.ssh/id_dsa
debug1: Trying private key: /home/guinsly/.ssh/id_ecdsa
debug1: Trying private key: /home/guinsly/.ssh/id_ed25519
debug1: No more authentication methods to try.
Permission denied (publickey).
```

My public key is named `lagotto_rsa.pub` and that's the one it's supposed to use by default but now it's seems like it can't find the public key.

```
ssh -i ~/.ssh/lagotto_rsa.pub ubuntu@pkp-alm.lib.sfu.ca -v
```

gives me also `Permission denied (publickey).`

```
-> % ssh -i ~/.ssh/lagotto_rsa.pub ubuntu@pkp-alm.lib.sfu.ca -v
OpenSSH_6.6.1, OpenSSL 1.0.1f 6 Jan 2014
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 19: Applying options for *
debug1: Connecting to pkp-alm.lib.sfu.ca [52.4.177.245] port 22.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: identity file /home/guinsly/.ssh/lagotto_rsa.pub type 1
debug1: identity file /home/guinsly/.ssh/lagotto_rsa.pub-cert type -1
debug1: Enabling compatibility mode for protocol 2.0
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_6.6.1p1 Ubuntu-2ubuntu2.3
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version OpenSSH_6.6.1p1 Ubuntu-2ubuntu2
debug1: match: OpenSSH_6.6.1p1 Ubuntu-2ubuntu2 pat OpenSSH_6.6.1* compat 0x04000000
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
debug1: kex: server->client aes128-ctr hmac-md5-etm@openssh.com none
debug1: kex: client->server aes128-ctr hmac-md5-etm@openssh.com none
debug1: sending SSH2_MSG_KEX_ECDH_INIT
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_ECDH_REPLY
debug1: Server host key: ECDSA c6:7c:32:1c:70:96:6e:ea:c0:84:96:79:3a:6c:06:bb
debug1: Host 'pkp-alm.lib.sfu.ca' is known and matches the ECDSA host key.
debug1: Found key in /home/guinsly/.ssh/known_hosts:21
debug1: ssh_ecdsa_verify: signature correct
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
debug1: Roaming not allowed by server
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_REQUEST sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Offering RSA public key: /home/guinsly/.ssh/lagotto_rsa.pub
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey
debug1: Offering RSA public key: guinslym@gmail.com
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey
debug1: Offering RSA public key: guinsly@guinsly-ThinkPad-L430
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey
debug1: Offering RSA public key: guinsly@guinsly-ThinkPad-L430
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey
debug1: No more authentication methods to try.
Permission denied (publickey).
```

I also tried it with the private key. I would like to know what have changed on my local machine that I can't access the remote anymore

Comment: Your question is [off-topic](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not your remote but your server at fault.  This errors happens only when you have changed permissions on your backend. It's a real nasty error and I could only solve it because my site was hosted on digital ocean and they give you console access. So it was only possible because of that.  There is nothing you can do from client side. I had asked a question about this on ask ubuntu check that link if you can.  Otherwise let me know

Comment: [the link](http://askubuntu.com/questions/698101/ssh-exchange-identification-read-connection-reset-by-peer-error) Read the comments section carefully you will find your answers there

Answer (score 1):

If you can connect to your server any other way, check the permissions of the `~/.ssh/` folder and `~/ssh/authorized_keys` file. They should be set to `700` and `600`, respectively.

You can also check `/var/log/auth.log` file to see what happens when you try to login. If your system has `systemd`, you can get more info with `sudo journalctl -u sshd`, or just `sudo journalctl`.

Comment: weird in my local I don't have `authorized_keys`. `chmod: cannot access ‘.~/ssh/authorized_keys’: No such file or directory`

Comment: The `authorized_keys` file I'm talking about is located on your server, not your local machine.

Comment: ok thanks...the night will be long :) I have to find a way to access it

Comment: Most cloud hosting providers have a way to access the server through a tty console in the admin interface.